# Clearing default text in TextInput on first click

Tags: python, kivy, textinputlayout

I have a [`TextInput()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html) widget that contains some default text.

[image]

When a user clicks inside the `TextInput`, the text that was initially inside the `TextInput` disappears (so that he can insert his own text *without* having to *manually* delete the default text).

1. Is there an alternative way to replicate the above behavior? (e.g. some
   already existing attribute of `TextInput`)
2. How can I make it reinsert automatically the text if the user didn't enter anything after clicking inside the `TextInput` and focused on some other widget. I tried `on_unfocus: self.text = "(optionally add a description of the bug here)"` but there is no `unfocus` attribute.

Code used:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<Main>:
    Button:
        text: 'Send bug report button'
    TextInput:
        never_selected: False
        text: '(optionally add a description of the bug here)'
        on_focus: if self.never_selected == False: self.text = ''; self.never_selected = True
""")


class Main(BoxLayout):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp
    runTouchApp(Main())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the docs: [hint_text property](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.hint_text)

It is a `StringProperty`, empty by default.